Is there an equivalent to Harvard Sentences in Korean
The Harvard sentences (Wikipedia, full list of sentences) are a set of English sentences that:

Are phonetically balanced in the sense that the phonemes that are used in the sentences appear at the same frequency they do in English.
Contain all phonemes that appear in English.

Here are a few examples of them:

Oak is strong and also gives shade.
Cats and dogs each hate the other.
The pipe began to rust while new.
Open the crate but don't break the glass.

Question: Is there an equivalent of the Harvard sentences for Korean, i.e. a phonetically balanced collection of Korean sentences containing all phonemes used in Korean?
